# ggplot multiple lines colored by y-value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to produce a graph that looks something like this image, but larger symbols on the data points, colored by their y-axis value:
[image]

Here is a 'minimal example' using the code I have tried:

```
library(ggplot2)
strtT <- Sys.time()-30*(24*3600);
endT <- Sys.time()-24*3600
xAxis <- seq(from=strtT,to=endT,by=24*3600)


dat <- data.frame(x = xAxis, 
                  y1 = rnorm(length(xAxis),mean=40,sd=30),
                  lab = "Y1")
fulldat <- dat;
dat <- data.frame(x = xAxis, 
                  y1 = rnorm(length(xAxis),mean=15,sd=5),
                  lab = "Y2")
fulldat <- rbind(fulldat,dat);
dat <- data.frame(x = xAxis, 
                  y1 = rnorm(length(xAxis),mean=80,sd=10),
                  lab = "Y3")
fulldat <- rbind(fulldat,dat);

gp<-ggplot(fulldat, aes(x,y1,color=y1)) + 
  # geom_point(aes(shape=(factor(lab)),size=6),show.legend=FALSE) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=(factor(lab)),size=6)) +
  # geom_line(aes(x,y1,linewidth=1.5,color=(14+as.numeric(factor(lab))))) +
  geom_line(aes(group=factor(lab)),linewidth=1.0) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours=c("blue","gray80","red"), limits=c(0,max(dat$y1)),
                        breaks=c(15,30,45,60,75,90,110), 
                        labels=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
                        na.value = "green",
                        guide=guide_colorbar(nbin=10, raster=F, barwidth=2, frame.colour=c("black"),
                                             frame.linewidth=1, ticks.colour="black")) +
  theme(legend.position = "right") 
gp
```

The biggest issue I cant work out is that I want the lines to be colored by the variable "lab", and the Y1 data as data points, colored by their y-axis value. In this example, both the data points and lines are colored by the y-axis value. It seems one cant separate the two.

Additional issue is to improve the looksof the legend. Color bar should be full height, and the legend for the line styles (lab variable) to be beside the color bar, not below. And what is that legend entry that says size with a solid point and '6'?? Can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general in `ggplot2` there is one scale per aesthetic, i.e. you can only have one `color` scale. One option to overcome this would be to use the `ggnewscale` package which allows to have multiple scales per aesthetic. Hence, map `y1` on `color` in `geom_point`, then add the `scale_color_gradientn` for `y1`. Afterwards add a new color scale via `ggnewscale::new_scale_color()` and add your lines plus your desired colors (in the example code I added a brewer pal via `scale_color_brewer`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(fulldat, aes(x, y1)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = lab, color = y1), size = 6) +
  scale_color_gradientn(
    colours = c("blue", "gray80", "red"), limits = c(0, max(dat$y1)),
    breaks = c(15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 110),
    labels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
    na.value = "green",
    guide = guide_colorbar(
      nbin = 10, raster = F, barwidth = 2, frame.colour = c("black"),
      frame.linewidth = 1, ticks.colour = "black"
    )
  ) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_line(aes(group = lab, color = lab), linewidth = 1.0) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  theme(legend.position = "right")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks stefan, great answer on a number of levels. It felt like I was allowed only one color scale per graph, which you stated to be true. The ggnewscale package will be a great help. And the scale_color_brewer looks to also be quite useful.